# How to pass an array of objects into $http.get params

Tags: c#, angularjs

I have an object called "ReferenceNumber". Reference numbers have a "Number" and a "Type".

The javascript object looks like this:

```
{
    "type" : ""
    "number" : ""
}
```

I need to send a list of these "ReferenceNumber"s to a C# System.Web.Http.ApiController. My method looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route(@"")]
public HttpResponseMessage MyMethod([FromUri]List<ReferenceNumber> refNumbers)
{ 
    ... 
}
```

I'm using $http from Angularjs to try to make all my API calls. I prefer to be able to do something like:

```
$http.get("MYURL", obj);
```

But I'm willing to use jQuery.param or JSON.stringify if need be. Or:

```
$http.get("MYURL", {params: {refNumbers: referenceNumbers}});
```

Or whatever. But no matter what combination of these things I try, including just hardcoding, I can't seem to get the list to be sent over. I can get a null list, an empty list, or a list with items in it with Number and Type properties that are null, but I can't get my data.

How can I send this data properly? Is sending a list simply not done?  And, if so, why is a list not acceptable? Should I package my list in an object? Must I use [FromBody] instead of [FromUri] and force my data in there?

Comment: I know Angular, but not ASP. What does you ASP service expect as query string? i.e. if you had to manually enter the URL to invoke this service with 2 reference numbers, what would you type?

Comment: Beg pardon, I may have the wrong tag. It is an System.Web.Http ApiController. I'll try to fix the tag.

Comment: "referenceNumbers "is a list of ReferenceNumber objects, not a single object. Each object in the list has a name and type property.

Comment: try simply doing: `{params: referenceNumbers}` .... then url would be `?number=123&type=sometype`

Comment: Please see the above comment. I need a list of these objects, not just a single object.

Comment: @K_Ram why don't you answer my question? If you had to manually enter the URL to invoke this service with 2 reference numbers, what would you type?

Comment: have u checked the url for the request, is it properly encoded, maybe it's broken somewhere

Comment: @JB Nizet: I would have answered your question sooner had I realized you edited your original question. I would probably try "MYURL?refNums={type:TYPE1, number:1234}&refNums = { type:TYPE2, number:24423}" and so forth.

Comment: @z.a.: As I can hit the controller, I assume that my url is correct, but the parameters are apparently not being encoded in such a way that they are received. Hence my question.

Comment: you will need to create that string yourself or try as JSON.stringify. Can do it in $httpInterceptors if need to use it frequently. Would make more sense to post it though

Comment: so you want them urlencoded then.  There are libraries for this.  Jquery doesn't seem to work right.

Comment: I've tried JSON.stringify and jQuery.param both and haven't had any success, unless I've used them terribly wrong. I've seen them work, used them myself, on complex objects, but not on lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably solved by now, but I'm posting my findings for the people that might come across this question in the future.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33855395/2687214) suggests to use the `$httpParamSerializerJQLike` param serializer. For me, it was the only way my C# back-end could understand that the parameter was an array of complex objects.

So in this specific case, you would have to do:

```
$http.get("MYURL", {params: {refNumbers: referenceNumbers}, paramSerializer: '$httpParamSerializerJQLike'});
```