# AngularJS GET ajax call with Array parameters

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I have already seen the following SO questions [Send array via GET request with AngularJS' $http service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957858/send-array-via-get-request-with-angularjs-http-service) and [Pass array of data from Angular $http POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275292/pass-array-of-data-from-angular-http-post). But the suggested solutions there does not seem to work for me. Mine is specifically about **array objects**.

I have the following AngularJS ajax call with array parameters

```
return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/PatientCategoryApi/PatCat',
    params: { "numbers[]": [{ First: 999, Second: 888 }]},
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/Json' }
})
```

The url generated by that call does not seem to work for me. I have tried various avatars of params, and the url generated (got them by using fiddler) are as follows.

```
params: { numbers: JSON.stringify([{ First: 999, Second: 888 }]) },
http://localhost:50849/api/PatientCategoryApi/PatCat?numbers=%5B%7B%22First%22:999,%22Second%22:888%7D%5D 

params: { "numbers[]": JSON.stringify([{ First: 999, Second: 888 }]) },
http://localhost:50849/api/PatientCategoryApi/PatCat?numbers%5B%5D=%5B%7B%22First%22:999,%22Second%22:888%7D%5D 

params: { "numbers[]": [{ First: 999, Second: 888 }]},
http://localhost:50849/api/PatientCategoryApi/PatCat?numbers%5B%5D=%7B%22First%22:999,%22Second%22:888%7D 

params: { numbers: [{ First: 999, Second: 888 }]},
http://localhost:50849/api/PatientCategoryApi/PatCat?numbers%5B%5D=%7B%22First%22:999,%22Second%22:888%7D
```

I want the url to be http://localhost:50849/api/PatientCategoryApi/PatCat?numbers[0][first]=999&numbers[0][second]=888. Because this is the only way my Asp.net MVC server side  code is able to understand and decipher the array.

One way is to set the url itself to hold the params fully as follows. The following is working. This is the last option for me.

```
return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/PatientCategoryApi/PatCat?numbers[0][first]=999&numbers[0][second]=888&numbers[1][first]=9999&numbers[1][second]=8888',
    //params: {...}, remove this completely
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/Json' }
})
```

But I want to understand, how to do this using params so AngularJS will do that for me.

Comment: what is your angular version ? I can see there is a fix for this in angular js 1.2.9..not sure though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - Send $http GET request with associative array params](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708103/angularjs-send-http-get-request-with-associative-array-params)

Comment: Seems that `jQuery.param({numbers: [{ First: 999, Second: 888 }]})` produces the result you expect. If you already have jQuery in your project, you can use it to construct the URL for you.

Comment: If you have jQuery then probably you can create params by jQuery and use it as follows - `var params = $.params({...});` then in angular `url: url+'?'+params`

Comment: But is it ok to use JQuery and AngularJS together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the [httpParamSerializerJQLike](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike)!  Use it like this:

```
$http({
  ...
  params: { "numbers": [{ First: 999, Second: 888 }]},
  paramSerializer: '$httpParamSerializerJQLike',
  ...
});
```

Or you can set it up as your default for all `$http` calls in a configuration block, like this:

```
angular.module('yourModuleName').config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.paramSerializer = '$httpParamSerializerJQLike';
});
```

Comment: Hi Eric, Thank you for the suggestion. I shall give it a try and let you know.

Comment: I pulled my hair for long. I knew there would be something like this very simple. More over by this method we dont need to get JQuery into the picture as suggested by others. Thank You once again Eric

Comment: Like the previous guy, I was getting crazy! Thought I'd have to make this mechanism by myself.. It saved my life!! Thank you!!!